# Making new field with formatted values in QGIS

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes, string

I have a column called `"Kiinteistötunnus"`. The values ​​are in the form 73479400010025.

Values in the whole column ​​should be changed to form 734-794-0001-0025.
The data type is Integer64. There are about 40000 individual values in that column, but the pattern is always the same: `###-###-####-####`.

Comment: The data type is Integer64. There are about 40000 individual values in that column, but the pattern is always the same. ###-###-####-####

Comment: Thanks Taras and MrXsquared. Solved this issue with your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
substr("Kiinteistötunnus",0,3)
||'-'||
substr("Kiinteistötunnus",4,3)
||'-'||
substr("Kiinteistötunnus",7,4)
||'-'||
substr("Kiinteistötunnus",11,4)
```

Make sure the new field is of type `string`